# How can I compile es5 to es6 using webpack and node (react front-end) on production?

Tags: babeljs, webpack-dev-server, babel-register

I was trying to use the require hook to use Babel to compile files from `es5` to `es6`. Unfortunately after running `npm install babel-register --save-dev` it still cannot find the module.

```
$ heroku logs
2017-09-10T00:52:40.511160+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'babel-register'
2017-09-10T00:52:40.511161+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2017-09-10T00:52:40.511162+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2017-09-10T00:52:40.511163+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-09-10T00:52:40.511163+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-09-10T00:52:40.511164+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/server.js:2:1)
2017-09-10T00:52:40.511164+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-09-10T00:52:40.511165+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-09-10T00:52:40.511165+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-09-10T00:52:40.511166+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-09-10T00:52:40.511166+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

My server.js file is reserved only for `es5` then it requires `index.js` which has all my imported components which are in `es6`.

```
// server.js

// only ES5 is allowed in this file

require("babel-register")({
  presets: [ 'es2015' ]
});

var app = require("./index.js");
```

Am I missing anything in my `package.json`?

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "youtube-instant-search",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Renders youtube videos after keystrokes",
  "main": "index.js",      
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "build": "babel src -d build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "webpack": "^1.15.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-addons-create-fragment": "^0.14.17",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-intl": "^2.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "youtube-api-search": "0.0.5"
  }
}
```

Here is the webpack config file

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/index.js"],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {        
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ],
    rules: [{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
        }, {
            loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
        }, {
            loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
        }]
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./"
  }
};
```

What seems to be my problem?

**EDIT**

Apparently, `babel-register` [is not ready for production](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5851). What would be my alternative? How can I compile `es5` to `es6` so that it is available for production? Can I do this using only `webpack` and `node`?